# How do i detect using python code if AWS region/ Availability is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am deploying critical application in AWS and want to cover scenario to detect 
AWS region failure or 
AWS Availability zone failure. 
Does AWS provide web hook or some APi to detect this?

Comment: You might be able to use: [AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/health.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Could you scrape information from that?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Just go to https://status.aws.amazon.com/ and figure out what message (or image link) correlates with a server being up (or down), parse out the fields into a table structure, and run your check. Python is a good language to learn if you want to start scraping. But this kind of scraping is so simple, there might be some commercial software you can use out-of-the-box, if you aren't inclined to learning coding right now.